# Passing argument to '.js.erb' template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I want to pass some arguments to the my Javascript template in Rails3 application
What I try with respond_to block is:

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.js({:id=>params[:id]})
    end
```

I also tried:

```
 respond_to do |format|
      format.js(params[:id])
    end
```

Am I forced to make id as an instance variable for the js template to use? How to pass variables to the template here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Does it work?

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render "action", :locals => {:id => params[:id]} }
end
```

"action" is your action / template name (index, show, etc.)

Comment: Antonio's comment makes more sense here. Defining the variable means you don't need to try and pass something extra.

Answer (score 15):

As an alternative you can define @variable in your controller and you should able to access it in your js.erb template. Then you don't need to pass variable in as parameter.

Comment: I think that Controllers should define less ivars as possible, right?